# Training face detection models from object detection repositories

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, face-detection

For training a model for face detection, is it possible to take a model for object detection and train it on a face detection data set (with only one class)? Are there any issues with having only 1 class for the object detection model?

The repository I am planning on using is: https://github.com/qfgaohao/pytorch-ssd

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is transfer learning. Without any further information about your problem, I think it's best to train both from scratch and using that pre-trained model to see which one performs better.

> Are there any issues with having only 1 class for the object detection model?

I am working on a medical project that focuses on detecting one class (lesion), so it's not something unusual in the field.

Comment: I don't think it is transfer learning if it's training from scratch? (transfer learning -> you train on a data set then on another dataset?)

Comment: If you are not doing TF then what's your concern? The model you cited is just an object detection model and the number of class should not be an issue. "Let's we are building a model to detect guns for security purpose." - This is a quote from the repo so I think it should be possible.